# How to use Lambda Expression as a String parameter C#

Tags: c#, string, lambda, delegates, messagebox

Just for curiosity, I would like to know if it is possible to use a Lambda Expression as a String parameter?

Here's my snipet:

```
List<Int64> selectedUsers = GetSelectedUsers();
if (MessageBox.Show(this, ((String message) =>
{
    message = "Are you sure you want to delete user(s) ID";
    foreach (Int64 id in selectedUsers)
    {
        message += " " + id.ToString();
    }
    message += "?";
    return message;
}), "Confirmation Delete User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    //DoSomething();
}
```

But unfortunately, I get this error "Error  7   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" here: (String message)

Thanks for your help, it is really appreciated!

Comment: Uh, no. What would you expect it to do? How do you expect `MessageBox.Show` to use the lambda expression? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Why do you think you should use a delegate at all?

Comment: Your lambda has to return a `string`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Well only to convert it to `Func<string, string>`... and that still won't work, because `MessageBox.Show` doesn't accept any delegates...

Comment: To build the message text.

Comment: Oh oki so usually it would work but because its a MessageBox it doesn't take any delegate?

Comment: @SteveRousseau Then why not build the message string before your call to MessageBox.Show() ?

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, of course. I suspect what he *really* wants to do is something like `selectedUsers.Aggregate()`.

Comment: @SteveRousseau it looks like you don't figure the difference between a type instance and a method which takes in parameter and/or return a type instance. Message.Box (and absolutely all other methods which expects a string) will never be able to accept something like what you wrote. Some people suggested you a working write, using an Invoke of a Func which returns string, but that's overkill for something like this !!

Comment: It's not really "usually it would work" - it only works for methods which *do* accept delegates (relatively rare, outside LINQ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your message before

```
string ids = selectedUsers.Select(n=>n.ToString()).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
// also works string.Join
// string ids = string.Join(", ",selectedUsers);
string message = "Are you sure you want to delete user(s) ID: "+ids+"?";
if (MessageBox.Show(this, message, "Confirmation Delete User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    //DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to just use `string.Join`? I'd consider that a lot more readable...

Comment: please note "selectedUsers.Select(n=>n.ToString()).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next)" could also be directly used as is in the MessageBox.Show call. No need to invoke it before (unless for some readibility concerns)

Comment: Thanks a lot @davcs86 !! For this particular situtation, I will choose the 'string.Join(", ",selectedUsers)' method since it seems more readable in this context.  But I keep the '((Func<string>)(() =>' for later!  Thanks you everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

If you ***really*** wanted to use a delegate of some sort to return a string (and I'm honestly not sure why you would here), you'd need to cast the expression to `Func<string>` and immediately invoke it.

```
if (MessageBox.Show(this, 
    ((Func<string>)(() =>
        {
            var message = "Are you sure you want to delete user(s) ID";
            foreach (Int64 id in selectedUsers)
            {
                message += " " + id.ToString();
            }
            message += "?";
            return message;
       })
    )(), 
    "Confirmation Delete User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
    { 
        //DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @David-L :) I decided to go with the String.Join for this design... but I noted your suggestion for the future!

Comment: @SteveRousseau That is certainly the better pattern.  I added my answer for completeness :).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you  should do

```
List<Int64> selectedUsers = GetSelectedUsers();

            if (MessageBox.Show(this, ((Func<string, string>)(message =>
            {
                message = "Are you sure you want to delete user(s) ID";
                foreach (Int64 id in selectedUsers)
                {
                    message += " " + id.ToString();
                }
                message += "?";
                return message;
            }))(""), "Confirmation Delete User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //DoSomething();
            }
        }
```

what we have here is an IFFE. As an optimization you could get rid of the message argument, since you're not really using the initial value. This would become :

```
List<Int64> selectedUsers = GetSelectedUsers();

            if (MessageBox.Show(this, ((Func<string>)(() =>
            {
                var message = "Are you sure you want to delete user(s) ID";
                foreach (Int64 id in selectedUsers)
                {
                    message += " " + id.ToString();
                }
                message += "?";
                return message;
            }))(), "Confirmation Delete User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //DoSomething();
            }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It will certainly work, but what an ugly piece of code for something so simple :). That's not a good way to take care of such concerns (but I know you're answering to OP's question) !

Comment: What's the difference with @David L's answer?